# Validating multiple files (IMG) in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating a website where I ask for a file in a form:

```
            <input id="foto-disfraz[]" name="foto-disfraz[]" type="file"/>
            <button type='button' class="agregarotra">Agregar otra foto</button>
            <span class="error"><?= $fotoErr ?></span>
```

You can add more files using the button "agregarotra" next to it , that uses a JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var nfotos = 1;
        $('.agregarotra').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (nfotos < 5) {
                $(this).before("<input id='foto-disfraz[]' name='foto-disfraz[]' type='file'/>");
                nfotos++;
            } else {
                alert("Ya tienes el máximo numero de fotos posibles");
            }
        });
    });
```

I have to validate every file added in the form, they are required so I must have at least one file.
If i have more I have to verify every file added by the user.
Right now im trying to at least verify one file, so my idea is to verify that foto-disfraz is not empty, and then adding to the variable $foto the file, so I can add it later to a database.

```
    $foto=$fotoErr='';
    ...
      if(isset($_FILES["foto-disfraz[]"])) {
        $foto = $_FILES["foto-disfraz[]"];
      }
      else {
        $fotoErr = "* Foto es obligatoria";
      }
    ...
    }
```

So right now my problem is that it always gives me the error, it seems that it doesnt save the file in the variable im trying to save to. I don't know if I'm using the `_FILE` method right or my condition on the if is failing due they can be multiple files or something.
I dont know what else I can add as detail so if I'm missing something important to add besides the code I can edit and update.

Comment: `$_FILES["foto-disfraz[]"]` is wrong. Just use `$_FILES["foto-disfraz"]` - you should find it contains an array of all the uploaded files. In case I'm wrong, you can always do `var_dump($_FILES);` as a debugging command to verify the structure and content of what the browser is sending.

Comment: Hey! it worked thank you! im stuck in a different thing now, i want to verify that the name of each file is not "", im struggling how to iterate through the [foto-disfraz]["name] because it doesnt have a constante value of how many names there will be.

Comment: Just use `foreach` over the `$_FILES` array and check each name as you go (though you should not have any empty names).

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["foto-disfraz[]"]` is wrong. the `[]` is used in the HTML element names to indicate to the browser that this is one of a set of elements whose values should be submitted as a list.

In the PHP, just use `$_FILES["foto-disfraz"]` - you should find it contains an array of all the uploaded files.

If you're curious, you can always do `var_dump($_FILES);` as a debugging command to verify the complete structure and content of the files the browser is sending.

To loop through the files, use a `foreach`, e.g.

```
if(isset($_FILES["foto-disfraz[]"])) 
{
  foreach ($_FILES["foto-disfraz"] as $file)
  {
    echo $file["name"];
  }
}
```

would simply echo the name of each uploaded file.